# Android Studio Unable to Build Module with Cross Module Dependancy

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-3.0

I have a project with 4 modules, say A, B, C, D. Module C is a container for common code in A, B and D. Module C uses Wire to generate Java Code from Protobuffers. Module B depends on both module C and D. I have only one compile project dependancy in B though, as B compiles D compiles C..

It was all working fine till Android Studio Update last year, when I "lost the editor", i.e. modules were still building nicely, but Android Studio when editing in module A and B missed the generated Java classes and painted my code "fairly" red, i.e. generated classes from C became unknown to the editor, losing syntax completion and all other stuff.

After opening a ticket at Google nothing happened. I went a while with the workaround having

```
 sourceSets {
    main.java.srcDirs += '../common/build/generated/source/java/'
}
```

in my (A or B) gradle. Which kept the editor intact, the project was building anyway.

With Android Studio 3.0 I do not get my modules built any more. With above sourceset line I end up with the dexer finding duplicate classes

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
Error:Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lde/spieleck/app/badgers/messages/BadgeMsg$Builder;
Error:com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lde/spieleck/app/badgers/messages/BadgeMsg$Builder;
Error:  at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:661)
Error:  at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:616)
Error:  at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:598)
Error:  at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
Error:  at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:198)
Error:  at com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerCallable.call(DexArchiveMergerCallable.java:61)
Error:  at com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerCallable.call(DexArchiveMergerCallable.java:36)
Error:  at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedCallable.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1445)
Error:  at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
Error:  at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:902)
Error:  at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1689)
Error:  at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1644)
Error:  at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lde/spieleck/app/badgers/messages/BadgeMsg$Builder;
Information:BUILD FAILED in 8s
Information:BUILD 61 FINISHED; failure=org.gradle.internal.exceptions.LocationAwareException: Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForDebug'.
Information:16 errors
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

Without above gradle lines, I end up with the compiler not finding code:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Unable to find source java class: 'D:\00meins\AndroidStudioProjects\Badgers-UI\common\build\generated\source\java\de\spieleck\app\badgers\messages\BadgeMsg.java' because it does not belong to any of the source dirs: '[D:\00meins\AndroidStudioProjects\Badgers-UI\app\src\main\java, D:\00meins\AndroidStudioProjects\Badgers-UI\app\src\debug\java, D:\00meins\AndroidStudioProjects\Badgers-UI\app\build\generated\source\r\debug, D:\00meins\AndroidStudioProjects\Badgers-UI\app\build\generated\source\buildConfig\debug, D:\00meins\AndroidStudioProjects\Badgers-UI\app\build\generated\source\aidl\debug, D:\00meins\AndroidStudioProjects\Badgers-UI\app\build\generated\source\rs\debug]'
```

Confused remark: When desparately I tried to downgrade gradle, gradle tools etc. withom Android Studio to state of previous Android Studio release gave up half the way due to more and more dependencies and got things back to the state that AS3.0 delivers and my modules built.

However after restarting AS3.0 I am back in above dilemma. I mean I cannot really edit my gradle settings back and forth everytime to get the built working.

Any suggestion how to set up my dependencies better or fix all compiling, building and syntax highlighting?

I am AFK now for a long weekend, hoping for answers early next week.

References:

1. G+: https://plus.google.com/u/0/+FrankNestel/posts/c177h2R1qJz
2. Google issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37120454

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a super answer, as things are complicated and real world. But Google support kindly inspected my setup and found out, that a certain source setting for generated code had become required, that was optional under AS2.2.

So, it probably won't happen, if you start with AS3 anyway. But as things got messy over time and suddenly stopped to work after migration, this wasn't exactly obvious to spot.